# UIViewController is not key value coding-compliant for the key XXXXX. No wrong connections in IB

Tags: ios, xcode

I get runtime error when displaying EditViewController from my main view controller:

```
'[<EditViewController 0x7fbef90> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key saveChanges.'
```

I've done all the different Google/Stack Overflow searches I can think of and all of my results refer to either a Tab Bar or a bad connection in Interface Builder. My project has no tab bar and I removed every connection (except that from the File's Owner, EditViewController, to the view) from every object in my nib. EditViewController does, in fact have a method named `-(IBAction)saveChanges`.

It's driving me crazy, and I can't figure out what on earth I'm supposed to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a thing that might help (not posting as an answer because this problem has multiple issue solutions) but whenever I connect something to an action/property in a XIB, then delete it without deleting the link, I get that error.  Check your connections for a small exclamation point (!) then delete that problem property/action.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but as noted above, there aren't any connections in this XIB except for connecting the view to the File's Owner.

Comment: Oh, in that case if you do not have any connections at all you need to connect the view outlet.  Otherwise it's like saying "I need you to show me this image, but the image doesn't exist"

Answer (score 7):

You may not have any invalid connections from the top `view` to an `IBOutlet` but check the `File's Owner` and `First Responder` for possible `IBAction`'s that have a connection to a method that is commented out or doesnt exist.

Another idea is to manually disconnect and reconnect each connection. I have experienced issues where I change an IBAction method from `- (IBAction)doStuff` to `- (IBAction)doStuff:(id)sender` after connecting in the IB but the connection still says `doStuff` when it should say `doStuff:`.  That colon doesnt look like much (and its hard as hell to distinguish in the IB) but it changes the action to `@selector(doStuff)` which is targeting a method that doesnt exist.

<sub>**Reconnecting couldn't hurt and has become my first troubleshooting step for most xib issues.**</sub>

---

Another sure way to find it is `grep` (from Terminal):

```
[ 22:20 jon@host ~ ]$ grep -RH "saveChanges" /path/to/${PROJECT_DIR}/*
```

---

[image: File's Owner Connections]

[image: First Responder Connections]

Comment: Thanks for the help, I hadn't even thought of using grep to find it. Unfortunately this didn't solve the problem, but I eventually solved it anyway (see my answer).

Answer (score 2):

I found this issue when trying to add connection to a nib that was for a `UITableViewCell`.
The File's Owner was set to a custom `UITableViewCell` class. But rather than that, do as usual: draging from the views directly into the .h file you must set the class of the `UITableViewCell` object. Then, connect things to that object; not the File's Owner (even though they are the same custom class underneath).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, but if you're having the same issue I would recommend trying any of the above methods first because mine is time consuming. I moved EditViewController.h/.m/.xib to my desktop and created new EditViewController.h/.m/.xib. I then rebuilt the xib by hand and copy/pasted the code from the original into the new one. Thankfully my xib wasn't too complicated.